# redbeanPHP database connect doesn´t work in phpUnit bootstrap

Tags: php, phpunit, redbean

i am using redbeanPHP since two years.
On my new project i wan´t to implement unit-tests from the beginning.

I installed phpUnit and without the database connection all works fine. I now wan´t to test my classes with database intigration. I know this is not a unit-test anymore. But i thing it will help me a lot to auto test the functionality from the implementation.

I call `R::setup("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ufm","root","root");` in my setup file which i declared as bootstrap file for phpUnit.

If i now run my tests i get:

`PDOException: Could not connect to database (ufm).
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php:280
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php:126
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php:289
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/Adapter/DBAdapter.php:79
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/QueryWriter/AQueryWriter.php:576
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/OODB.php:893
phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/core/plugins/rb.phar/RedBeanPHP/Facade.php:463
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ufm/tests/TurnierTest.php:14`

The strange thing is that i am using the same setup file in my normal application. There all works fine.

Has phpUnit or redbeanPHP any limitations for database connection in the bootstrap file? I searched for two days now but i can´t find any documentation about this. I only found a blogpost on google groups where some guy successfully makes the exact same thing.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards,schw4ndi

Comment: A other solution would be to intigrate phpUnit database testing (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html). But i can´t find a solution with redbeanPHP for it. Has anyone integrated redbeanPHP to phpUnit database testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled accros the same error again. 
Just change the localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it works fine! Maybe it helps someone in the future.

```
R::setup("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ufm","root","root");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
R::setup("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ufm;port=3306","root","root");
```

I added port number there see if that helps.

If you need a working Test Unit + Redbean example, you can try skully framework here: http://github.com/triodigital/skully-project

### Setting up

1. Clone this project to your server.
2. Copy config/config.unique.php.original to config/config.unique.php and update the database information there.
3. Update baseUrl config in config/config.common.php.
4. Copy .htaccess.original to .htaccess and update the first line of that file.
5. Update the project by running './composer.phar install'.

Comment: Port number doesnt help. See my answer above. But thanks for the test project!